# Active admin - checkbox doesn't make batch action enabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I install

```
gem 'activeadmin',         github: 'gregbell/active_admin', branch: 'rails4'
```

and it works fine but.. When i click on checkbox for some resources, batch action doesn't change to enabled. I have:

```
  index do |description|
   selectable_column
   column :id
   column :user
   column :description
   default_actions
  end



batch_action :destroy, :confirm => "delete ??", :plural_model => "descriptions" do |selection|
Profile.find(selection).each { |d| d.reset_description! }
redirect_to collection_path
  end
```

and batch action for :destroy. Is active admin works correct in rails 4?

Comment: ok i havent got //= require active_admin/base in my own active_admin.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem, the first comment of the OP solved it for me:
Add

```
//= require active_admin/base
```

to

```
active_admin.js
```

Answer (score 0):

I just add selectable_column like this:

```
index do
  selectable_column
  id_column
  column :title
  column :value
  column :featured
  column :page_title
  selectable_column  #<--- this one works fine
  actions
end
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that the required Javascript files were not loaded on the local server. When pushed to production, everything worked just fine.